# Jquery, if div has class that contains some word(variable) than remove that class

Tags: jquery, html

I have the class `.wrapper`

Also I have a color-pallete to change the `background` on the page and the `main color` of some items.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="color-picker">
    <div class="">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="col-md-6"><span id="Theme" class="light"></span></li>
            <li class="col-md-6"><span id="Theme" class="dark"></span></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="col-md-3"><span id="Color" class="red"></span></li>
            <li class="col-md-3"><span id="Color" class="yellow"></span></li>
            <li class="col-md-3"><span id="Color" class="blue"></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$(".color-picker span").click(function () 
{
    var valcolor = $(this).prop('class');
    var valtype = $(this).prop('id');

    $(".wrapper").addClass(valcolor + valtype);

});
```

How Can I remove the classes from my wrapper that contains the same `valltype` property that the element i have clicked on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st:** Id must be unique

**2nd:** read about [**selectors**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

```
$(".wrapper [class*='"+ valtype  +"']")
```

> *=  // if this contains
>
> ^= // if starts with
>
> $= // if ends with

**Additional :** I know `.prop()` will work .. but I used to use `.attr()` instead

**Edit after your comment** *(as I said Id must be unique use data attribute instead)*

**in html**

```
<div class="wrapper" data-theme="" data-color="">This is Wrapper Div</div>
<div class="color-picker">
    <div class="">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="col-md-6"><span data-id="Theme" class="light">Theme - light</span></li>
            <li class="col-md-6"><span data-id="Theme" class="dark">Theme - dark</span></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="col-md-3"><span data-id="Color" class="red">Color - red</span></li>
            <li class="col-md-3"><span data-id="Color" class="yellow">Color - yellow</span></li>
            <li class="col-md-3"><span data-id="Color" class="blue">Color - blue</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**in js**

```
$(".color-picker span[data-id='Theme']").click(function () {

    var valTheme = $(this).attr('class');
    $(".wrapper").attr('data-theme' , valTheme);
    var GetwrapperTheme = $(".wrapper").attr('data-theme');
    alert(GetwrapperTheme);
});
$(".color-picker span[data-id='Color']").click(function () {
    var valcolor = $(this).attr('class');
    $(".wrapper").attr('data-color' , valcolor);
    var GetwrapperColor = $(".wrapper").attr('data-color');
    alert(GetwrapperColor);
    $(".wrapper").css('color', valcolor);
});
```

in css

```
.wrapper{
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  color : #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align : center;
}
.wrapper[data-theme="light"]{
  background : #eee;
}
.wrapper[data-theme="dark"]{
  background : #ccc;
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/gd7kR/280/)

Comment: Thank you!

I used the same script to find that div, but I can't understand how to remove the class i need.. if I click on span that has an `id="Color" and class="blue"` then jQuery will add to wrapper a class called **"blueColor"**, so when I click on another span, for example with `id="Color" and class="red" `I wnat to remove the first class, called **"blueColor"**

And i want to find that class by the second part, it might be the **Color** or **Theme**

Comment: Thank you so much! I will inspect all of your code to learn how it works!
And again, Thank you! :)

Comment: @ДенисРябоштанов you're welcome .. the code is very simple .. just use data attribute to make things easier .. Good Luck to you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".color-picker span").click(function (){

  if($(this).is('.valtype')){

     $(this).find('.valtype').remove();
   }

})
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on why and how this code answers the question.